# SSL signed certificate Authentication in Gatling

Tags: java, scala, ssl, https, gatling

I need to talk to a service which requires CA signed certificates. I have certificates on my own username and the same certificates has been imported at the server side.So that when I send request, I will produce my certificate for authentication with the server and server matches those certificate and send the response back.

When I request the URL in the browser, it automatically selects/asks (In pop-up) with the certificate on my username and when I select that user name the request loads with a proper response.

Now I want to simulate the same thing in Gatling. However in Gatling I am getting a 401 (Unauthorized).

I verified at the server side that when I send the request from browser, I can able to see the certificates are passing but when I send request from Gatling the certificates are not sending along with request for authentication. At the server side it says no certificates found.

I have imported my username CA signed certificates into JDK keystore and sending the request as shown below.

```
def execute(): ScenarioBuilder = {
val parameters = Map("$filter" -> "${Id}")
val positionsScenario: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Locations")
  .feed(accountFeed)
  .exec(requestHandler.getSAPRequest("Locations", parameters))
positionsScenario
}

def getRequest(requestName: String, parameters: Map[String, String]): ChainBuilder = {
val messageBuilder = exec(http(requestName)
  .get(s"$uri")
  .queryParamMap(parameters)
  .check(status.is(200))
)
messageBuilder
}
```

I have configured my certs using system.property since gatling.conf is not sending the the certificates in the scenario.

```
    System.setProperty("gatling.http.ssl.trustStore.file", "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/security/cacerts")
    System.setProperty("gatling.http.ssl.trustStore.password", "changeit")
    System.setProperty("gatling.http.ssl.trustStore.type", "JKS")

    System.setProperty("gatling.http.ssl.keyStore.file", "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/security/vikram")
    System.setProperty("gatling.http.ssl.keyStore.password", "changeit")
    System.setProperty("gatling.http.ssl.keyStore.type", "JKS")
```

**Here are the log from gatling**

```
    Session(SAPPositions,4,Map(gatling.http.ssl.keyStore.password -> changeit, 
    gatling.http.cache.dns -> io.gatling.http.resolver.ShuffleJdkNameResolver@6e027c67, 
    gatling.http.ssl.trustStore.type -> JKS, gatling.http.ssl.trustStore.password -> changeit, 
    accountId -> (account_id eq '000194878-182182-AU-AUD'), 
    gatling.http.ssl.keyStore.file -> C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/security/vikram, 
    gatling.http.ssl.keyStore.type -> JKS, gatling.http.referer -> https://d3u.internal.com/sap/op/data/ACCOUNT_LOCATION_API_SRV/locationapi?%24filter=%28account_id%20eq%20%27000194878, 
    gatling.http.ssl.trustStore.file -> C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/security/cacerts, 
    gatling.http.cookies -> CookieJar(Map(CookieKey(sap-usercontext,d3u.internal.com,/) -> StoredCookie(sap-usercontext=sap-client=100; path=/,true,false,1517797866679))))
 1517797866640,0,KO,List(),io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry$$Lambda$458/906347731@1443b002)
=========================
HTTP request:
GET https://d3u.internal.com/sap/op/data/ACCOUNT_LOCATION_API_SRV/locationapi?%24filter=%28account_id%20eq%20%27000194878
headers=
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: d3u.internal.com
=========================
HTTP response:
status=
401 Unauthorized
headers= 
set-cookie: sap-usercontext=sap-client=100; path=/
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
sap-system: D3U
www-authenticate: Basic realm="SAP NetWeaver Application Server [D3U/100]"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

**Here are my Server side log:**

```
[Thr 139749210060544]   Server-configured Ciphersuites: "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES256_GCM_SHA384:T
[Thr 139749210060544] Mon Feb  5 11:09:34 2018
[Thr 139749210060544]   Client-offered Ciphersuites: "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES256_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_S
[Thr 139749210060544]   No Client Certificate
[Thr 139749210060544]   New session (TLSv1.2, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES128_CBC_SHA)
[Thr 139749210060544]   HexDump of new SSL session ID { &buf= 7f19c001306c, buf_len= 32 }
[Thr 139749210060544]    00000: 3e 2d 9e fb b6 f3 bf 63  fb 49 27 75 f3 d8 24 c7   >-.....c .I'u..$.
[Thr 139749210060544]    00010: 90 85 bb ed 5e 39 d6 cc  15 27 25 04 fe 29 44 3f   ....^9.. .'%..)D?
[Thr 139749210060544]   SapSSLISessionStartFin(sssl_hdl=7f19c0016b50)==SAP_O_K
[Thr 139749210060544]  in/out: status = "new SSL session,TLSv1.2,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES128_CBC_SHA, **NO client cert"**
[Thr 139749210060544] <<- SapSSLSessionStartNB(sssl_hdl=7f19c0016b50)==SAP_O_K
[Thr 139749210060544] HttpParseRequestHeader: no content length set
[Thr 139749210060544] HttpParseRequestHeader: no transfer-encoding set
[Thr 139749210060544] HttpParseRequestHeader: Version: 1001
[Thr 139749210060544] HttpParseRequestHeader: Keep-Alive: 0
[Thr 139749210060544] HttpParseRequestHeader: no server port set
[Thr 139749210060544] HTTP request (raw) [5/540445/1]:
[Thr 139749210060544]   GET /sap/bc/gui/sap/its/webgui?sap-client=000 HTTP/1.1
[Thr 139749210060544]   host: d3u.internal.com
[Thr 139749210060544]   connection: Close
[Thr 139749210060544] Connection Info: role=Server, local=vd3u01.internal.com:44300, peer=10.137.249.2, protocol=HTTPS
[Thr 139749210060544] ->> SapSSLGetPeerInfo(sssl_hdl=7f19c0016b50, &cert=7f19e605e990, &cert_len=7f19e605e99c,
[Thr 139749210060544]    &subject_dn=7f19e605e988, &issuer_dn=7f19e605e978, &cipher=7f19e605e980)
[Thr 139749210060544] <<- SapSSLGetPeerInfo(sssl_hdl=7f19c0016b50)==SAP_O_K
[Thr 139749210060544]     out: cert_len = <no cert>
[Thr 139749210060544]     out: cipher   = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES128_CBC_SHA"
```

In the server side log, it says client certificate not sent. I am suspecting I am sending something wrong in the request or my code itself.

Thanks

Comment: Any idea whats wrong here?

Comment: It looks like the client side certificates are not sent. Any body help who knows gatling well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out what's the problem. The certificates which I am producing are not valid certificates to authenticate with the server.

**How do I know whether they are valid/invalid?**

Just enabled the java debug using the below line

`System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all")` and see the debug line when the gatling initially starts. I see everything empty which is suspicious to me.

```
keyStore is : C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/security/vthaduri
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is :
```

**Use javax.net.ssl**      [Just for debugging purpose]

Also I have used `javax.net.ssl` instead of `gatling.http.ssl` for setting trustore and keystore.

**Lastly  `.disableClientSharing`**

```
val httpBuilder: HttpProtocolBuilder = http
      .disableClientSharing
      .baseURL(AppConfig.getRuntimeConfig("endpoints." + environment + ".sap"))
      .connectionHeader("Keep-Alive")
      .acceptHeader("*/*")
      .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
```

Later I configured everything properly as per galting.

Comment: disableClientSharing was dropped. More info https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/d589d9fc9c74b99492a8a8b1a721d76b2d25b6a4/src/sphinx/migration_guides/2.3-to-3.0.rst